# How to connect to remote MySQL database from Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: mysql, database, windows-phone-8, remote-access

I'm developing application for windows phone 8 and I need to get user data from remote MySQL database. This database is also used by the web-application.

What is the solution for this problem? Where I can read some information about using remote data storages with windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the restsharp client for windows phone. Its fully documented and a nuget install is also available. heres the link http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 0):

A better and simpler way is to perform all the db operations in server side code (like php) and the information can be passed to the php file using a query string and the reverse by echo statement.

```
var webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://website.com/filename.php?name=" + myname.Text );
webclient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(handler);

private void opener(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
            string response = reader.ReadLine();

            MessageBox.Show(response);
    }
}
```